# JSON-ification and processing of data with Python

Tags: python, json

My script looks like this:

```
with open('toy.json', 'rb') as inpt:

    lines = [json.loads(line) for line in inpt]

    for line in lines: 
        records = [item['hash'] for item in lines]
    for item in records: 
        print item
```

What it does is read in data where each line is valid JSON, but the file as a whole is *not* valid JSON. The reason for that is because it's an aggregated dump from a web service.

The data looks, more or less, like this:

```
{"record":"value0","block":"0x79"} 
{"record":"value1","block":"0x80"}
```

The code works, it allows me to interact with the data as JSON, but it's so slow that it's essentially useless. Is there a good way to speed up this process?

Answer (score 1):

It's slow because of this line:

> ```
> for line in lines: 
>     records = [item['hash'] for item in lines]
> ```

Notice that `records` will be overwritten for each line.
And in fact it's overwritten with the exact same value for each line.
In fact you could replace this loop with just this line:

```
records = [item['hash'] for item in lines]
```

That should already solve the problem with the slowness.
But I would go one step further and get `records` in one step,
by getting `hash` directly during the first pass over the input lines:

```
with open('toy.json', 'rb') as input:
    records = [json.loads(line)['hash'] for line in input]

    for item in records: 
        print item
```

Comment: He might want to keep `lines` around to get other fields from the JSON later in the code.